# Access to each matrix point

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, cuda

I have a problem when I try to get access to each point of matrix in CUDA kernel. I'm working with OpenCV and I'm trying to "do something" on each point of matrix. 
So, I'm converting `uint8_t` matrix to `float` matrix like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<inputMatrix.rows; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<inputMatrix.cols * cn; j+=cn){                           
        examMatrix[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 0] = pixelPtr[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 0]; // B
        examMatrix[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 1] = pixelPtr[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 1]; // G
        examMatrix[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 2] = pixelPtr[i*inputMatrix.cols*cn + j + 2]; // R               
    }
}
```

And this works for 3 channels image cause if I created output image from this matrix (after back conversion to `uint8_t`) looks same as input.
But I want to make some changes using CUDA:

I set block size and grid size like this:

```
dim3 dimBlock(count, 3);
dim3 dimGrid( frameHeight/count, frameWidth/count);
```

Where `count` is thread number, `3` is channel number, `frameHeight` and `frameWidth` are frame size.

So, I allocated `GPUexamMatrix` and `GPUresultMatrix` and tried to access to each point in kernel. My kernel looks like this:

```
resultMatrix[(blockIdx.x * blockIdx.y) + (threadIdx.x * threadIdx.y)] = examMatrix[(blockIdx.x * blockIdx.y) + (threadIdx.x * threadIdx.y)];
```

So, as you can see I tried to simply copy matrix. After this operation, when I returned my matrix to host and printed it I've got really small or really big `float` numbers inside matrix, but not the numbers from examine matrix.

I suppose I'm doing something wrong inside kernel. Any ideas?

Comment: that looks like uninitialized values. or broken values due to a race condition. you should run `cuda-memcheck` on your application to narrow it down.

Comment: `frameHeight/count` - you sure it's fine with integer division?

Comment: I'm pretty shure it's fine, cause I'm testing when count = 1.

Comment: In cuda-memcheck I've got:

    ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit error 11 on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so [0x311b30]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.6.0 (cudaMemcpy + 0x1df) [0x33f9f]
=========     Host Frame:./gauss_gpu [0x2381]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21de5]
=========     Host Frame:./gauss_gpu [0x1c79]
=========

Comment: that means `cudaMemcpy` returned `cudaErrorInvalidValue`

Comment: Ok, let's say that I will use one dimensional block size:
dim3 dimBlock(count);
and two dimensional grid size:
dim3 dimGrid( frameHeight/count, frameWidth/count);
How in this approach make an unique indexing of each matrix point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the built-in variables can't possibly be correct. To give just one simple example, threadIdx.x = 0 and threadIdx.y = 2 will access the same point as threadIdx.x = 2 and threadIdx.y = 0. You don't have unique indexing. I could try and give you something that will work, but I'm a little confused by your dimBlock variable. In short, this is not how I would set up grid/block/indexing to handle a 2D array. I wouldn't use 3, the channel number, in my threadblock dimensioning

Try something like this:

```
// make sure count is small like 16: count*count<512 or 1024 depending on GPU
dim3 dimBlock(count, count);
dim3 dimGrid( frameWidth/dimBlock.x, frameHeight/dimBlock.y);
```

and in your kernel:

```
int row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
int col = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

resultMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 0] = examMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 0];
resultMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 1] = examMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 1];
resultMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 2] = examMatrix[3*(row*frameWidth + col) + 2];
```

The above assumes `frameWidth` and `frameHeight` are evenly divisible by `count`

Comment: Awesome! It's work. Finally I wrote my program, thank you very much :)